# Why this program is giving the output at -25 in spite of variables being unsigned integer

Tags: c++, c

1.The code defines the variables as unsigned integer however the output is shown negative.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<limits.h>
#include<stdint.h>
int main(){
    uint32_t a= 25,b=50;
    a = a-b;    
    printf("\n%d\n",a);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's because you told `printf` to print a `%d`, which is a signed integer. That's what `%d` means. A computer always does exactly what you tell it to do, instead of what you want it to do.

Answer (score 1):

The correct format specifier would be (The macro `PRIu32` is defined in `inttypes.h` header ).

```
printf("%" PRIu32 "\n",a);
```

`%d` expects the arguments passed to it would be address of an `signed int` - that's why the value you passed is considered as `signed int`. After you have used the correct format specifier the output would be `UINT32_MAX+1-25`.

Using the wrong format specifier is *undefined behavior*.

Comment: It may be worth adding that the `PRIu32` macro is defined in the `inttypes.h` header file.

Comment: @DavidBowling.: Thanks for the suggestion.